# Robot framework | jybot not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: robotframework

While executing our robot framework scripts, we get error :  `"jybot is not recognized as internal or external command"`

**Steps followed for installation:**

```
installed python and set path in environment variables
installed jython and set path in environment variables
installed robotframework using robotframework-2.9.1.win-amd64.exe
```

while installing robotframework only two files were created "`pybot`" ,"`rebot`" and "`robot`" . We created `jybot .bat` file and set path of run.py file created in python\lib\site-packages\robot folder

our application has build over java swing, so we have created one wrapper file in python. we have placed everything in jython folder and trying to execute test cases.

error while execution `-- jybot is not recognized as internal or external command.`

could you please suggest a solution to this issue

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you have not installed robotframework to jython interpreter. 
Verify this by checking list of packages in jython by pip:

```
jython -m pip list
```

or checking if robot is really installed:
`jython -m robot.run`

If there is no pip or no robotframework package in list:

- install pip to jython (easist is to download get-pip.py from web and run jython get-pip.py)
- run pip from jython and install robot:

`jython -m pip install robotframework`